# Python: Get name of list as string

Tags: python

I have a program in python similar to:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
L = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for l in L:
    d[l].append('')
```

In my actual program I populate each sublist with somedata, but then I would like to go over each list individually and perform some action. I can get all of it working, but in an effort to write an ouptut for part of the loop I would like to print the name of the sublist I am working with.

For instance:

```
for List in d:
    print str(List)
```

of course this is wrong and will just print the content of the list as a string. I want to get the name of the string so my output would be:

```
'A'
'B'
'C'
```

Comment: The loop "for List in d" that you wrote above will in fact print out the dictionary keys ("names of lists"), not "list contents", as you expect. Try it again!

Comment: I'm confused. The code you posted will print A, B, and C. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are already in a dictionary right? Just use the keys of the dictionary.

```
for key, val in d.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Or, if you just want to iterate over the keys, you can use what you were originally using (iterating over a dictionary just iterates over the keys by default), or for more clarity you can iterate over the `keys()` method.

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
```